# Datatype in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have come across the following statement in numpy:

```
x=numpy.zeros((2,2),dtype=[('x','i4'),('y','i4')])
```

and the output is like this:

```
[[(0,0)(0,0)]    
 [(0,0)(0,0)]]
```

What is the meaning of `[('x','i4'),('y','i4')]`? Please explain.

Comment: Please see [Structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

Answer (score 5):

This is how the elements of the array are given a name and datatype.

In this case, the names of the first elements of each entry in the array can be accessed using `'x'` and the second elements can be accessed using `'y'`:

```
>>> x['x']
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
>>> x['y']
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

This is clearer if we change one of the entries:

```
>>> x['x'] = numpy.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
>>> x
array([[(1, 0), (1, 0)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 0)]], dtype=[('x', 'i4'), ('y', 'i4')])
```

As you can see, the first element in each entry has been changed.

The `'i4'` parts specify the datatype of the elements. Specifically:

`i` means signed integer

`4` means a 4-byte size

See the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) for Structured arrays, dtype denotes the data type of the values in the numpy array.

`[('x','i4'),('y','i4')]` means `x` is a 32-bit integer and `y` is also a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

Here i4 is a 4-byte (32-bit) integer.

You will find more details in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html (i4 is about halfway down the page).